# Как ограничить количество вводимых символов в поле?

Tags: php

На некоторых сайтах есть ограничение на количество вводимых символов в какое-то поле (например, оставления комментария), после набора максимального количества символов дальше ничего уже не вводится, как сделать это ограничение?

Comment: Разобрался сам, поделись с другими.
Как ограничить количество вводимых символов в <textarea> Кириллица - 70 Латиница - 160

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если поле `input type=text`, то задается `maxlength`; если `textarea`, то нужен javascript ). Да и то всё это можно обойти) На пхп можно через `strlen` проверить длину введенных данных и если они больше `х` - вернуть ошибку)
Так пример чего Вам нужен? html, javascript, php??

Comment: Да, я уже разобрался.

Comment: хотел бы уточнить - если юзается utf-8 то не `strlen` а `mb_strlen`<br>
Вообще абсолютно солидарен, причем тут php я тоже не понял...

Comment: а я не знал, что разница есть)) хотя да, я только на днях проект на утф перевёл)

Answer (score 2):

Вот для всех браузеров с поддержкой `paste`,

```
$('.limited').bind('keyup keydown paste',function(e) {
    var $t=$(this);
    setTimeout(function(){ 
    var max=$t.attr('maxlength')*1;
    if ($t.val().length>max) {
        $t.val($t.val().substr(0,max));
    }
    $t.next().children('span').text(max-$t.val().length);
    },0);

});
```

`setTimeout` необходим, для того, чтобы строка таки попала в поле, и тогда, с ней можно работать.

[демо](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/rR7Qd/)